# KeepAwake Module - Cannot find type '' in scope

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

## Issue

I am working with a react-native codebase that has been ejected. This codebases libraries were very far out of date. I have done an npm outdate check and update every package. This is because it was a nightmare working with old libraries and builds in xcode were unreliable along with the fact our app would no longer work as expected.

## Question

Upon updating I got many build errors in xCode that I have been resolving one by one. I am now stumped on this error, has anyone seen this before?:

`Cannot find type 'Module' in scope` <-- this is found in the "KeepAwakeModule".

> There are many other errors like this, but this is the top one.

I put the contents of this file at the bottom.

I tried googling this but no luck. Its seems like the expocoremodules are not importing the keepawake module or that module does have any of the other items available. I did do a fresh pod install and yarn install as well as cleared my builds but no luck. i am providing the keep awake module along with my *.Podfile* and both *delegate* files below

Here are the files

## Package.json before

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle — entry-file index.js — platform ios — dev false — bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle — assets-dest ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker": "^1.2.14",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.15.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~2.3.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-notifications": "0.8.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.3.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-axios": "2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.1",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.403.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^6.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-switch": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.11.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.14.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.8.2",
    "react-native-wheel-picker-android": "^2.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "pdi-app-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

## Package.json After:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle — entry-file index.js — platform ios — dev false — bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle — assets-dest ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker": "^1.2.16",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-device": "^5.0.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.17.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.17.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.6",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.2",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.1.8",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1293.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.19.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-switch": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.12",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-native-wheel-picker-android": "^2.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.20.12",
    "babel-jest": "~29.4.1",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "~18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "pdi-app-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

## AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>
#import <Expo/Expo.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <UMCore/UMAppDelegateWrapper.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate, EXUpdatesAppControllerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <TSBackgroundFetch/TSBackgroundFetch.h>

#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>
#import <EXSplashScreen/EXSplashScreenService.h>
#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistryProvider.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *launchOptions;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
    InitializeFlipper(application);
  #endif
  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  if([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  
NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
    
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"]; 

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                        moduleProvider:nil
                                        launchOptions:launchOptions];

    #if RCT_DEV
      [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
    #endif
      RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge
                                                      moduleName:@"Test"
                                                      initialProperties:nil];                                    

  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

[[TSBackgroundFetch sharedInstance] didFinishLaunching];

  return YES;
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  }
}

- (RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
 }

- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
  return extraModules;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
 #else
  return [[EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance] launchAssetUrl];
 #endif
}

- (void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {
  appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  EXSplashScreenService *splashScreenService = (EXSplashScreenService *)[UMModuleRegistryProvider getSingletonModuleForClass:[EXSplashScreenService class]];
  [splashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:self.window.rootViewController];
}

@end
```

## PodFile

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'pdimobile' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_flipper! # should match the version of your Flipper client app


  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral"
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
```

## Keep Awake Module

```
// Copyright 2021-present 650 Industries. All rights reserved.

import ExpoModulesCore

public final class KeepAwakeModule: Module {
  private var activeTags = Set<String>()

  public func definition() -> ModuleDefinition {
    Name("ExpoKeepAwake")

    AsyncFunction("activate") { (tag: String) -> Bool in
      if self.activeTags.isEmpty {
        setActivated(true)
      }
      self.activeTags.insert(tag)
      return true
    }

    AsyncFunction("deactivate") { (tag: String) -> Bool in
      self.activeTags.remove(tag)
      if self.activeTags.isEmpty {
        setActivated(false)
      }
      return true
    }

    AsyncFunction("isActivated") { () -> Bool in
      return DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        return UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled
      }
    }

    OnAppEntersForeground {
      if !self.activeTags.isEmpty {
        setActivated(true)
      }
    }

    OnAppEntersBackground {
      if !self.activeTags.isEmpty {
        setActivated(false)
      }
    }
  }
}

private func setActivated(_ activated: Bool) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = activated
  }
}
```

I did create a new bare react-native project just to see that libraries being used and to ensure there were not file structure changes needed with my upgrade. I do notice the AppDelegate files are now in a builds folder and the .m has a new extension `.mm` Could this be more problem? If so, how do I properly configure my codebase to support this?

Comment: I'm having the save issue now. Could you fix the issue?